# `free()` wrapper

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm experimenting with writing `malloc` and `free` wrappers, and I wonder why does the following code gives error `pointer being freed was not allocated`, why does not `delete()` work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define log(v) printf(#v " == %d \n", v)
#define new(n, type) _new((n), sizeof(type), __LINE__, __FILE__)

void *_new(int n, size_t size, int line, char *file)
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(n * size);

    if (ptr == NULL) 
    {
        printf("new(): Memory allocation error, file \"%s\", line %d. \n", file, line);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return ptr;
}

void delete(int *ptr)
{
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}


main()
{  
    int *p;

    p = new(1, int);
    log(p);

    delete(&p);
    log(p);
}
```

Comment: Side note: Just be careful you don't try to compile this in a C++ compiler...

Comment: Your code is not compilable. If your compiler's error checking is loose enough to accept this code, it at least must issue some warnings about serious errors present in your code. Until you fix these errors, there's not much sense in analyzing your code's behavior. What you have now is just a meaningless mish-mash of invalid pointer operations.

Comment: @Mehrdad: or for that matter a C compiler, since it uses the identifier `_new`, which is reserved at file scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you,

```
int *p;
p = new(1, int);
delete(&p);
```

Then you should

```
void delete(int** ptr) //two ** here!!
{
    free(*ptr);
    *ptr = NULL;
}
```

Comment: On a sidenote: Try to look at your compiler's warnings too. Sometimes they are helpful `:)`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're `free()`ing the thing the pointer is pointing to (`*ptr`), not the pointer `ptr` itself.</strike>
Missed the `&` in the `delete()` call; sorry.

Comment: @aschepler that only means the particular use of `delete` is ok, it's definition is still incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is this line

```
free(*ptr);
```

The `free` function is expecting a pointer value but you're giving it an `int` instead.  Try this

```
free(ptr);
```

**EDIT**

Why the downvotes?  The `delete` function is flat out incorrect with respect to the usage of free and my statements about it are correct.  The fact that the specific incorrect usage of `delete` makes it all kinda work (it's correctness is platform dependent) doesn't make my answer incorrect.