# C - free() wrapper for deallocation's best practices

Tags: c, free

The best practice for free() is to assign a NULL after freeing a "dynamically allocated" pointer.
But having 50 instances of:
`free(p);   p = NULL;`
Isn't the most compelling.
So I thought about creating a function that does it and calling it SmartFree(), but for some reason It creates issues for me.
Any body has an example for such function?
FYI - I saw this post [`free()` wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573703/free-wrapper)
But I would like to use that function to free many data types. So I used void *, but Im concerned that's part of the issue.

Comment: You can use a macro: `#define FREE(p) do { free(p); p = 0; } while(0)` but I question whether it's really a best practice to zero pointers when they're freed. The best practice is to develop a coding style where use-after-free is avoided, for example by making ownership clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\`free()\` wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573703/free-wrapper)

Comment: You don't need to be concerned about the void data type. `free` doesn't care about the data type anyway. BTW what exactly is the issue you mention in "...SmartFree(), but for some reason It creates issues for me". Where is your code?

Comment: @PaulHankin just curious: why would you doubt that it is a good practice to reset the pointers after they’re freed? you’re not writing to unallocated memory, you just point back to NULL. after all, many managed runtimes do it exactly that way to prevent writing to memory addresses they no longer may access.

Comment: While you may find something that satisfies your taste a bit better, there is nothing at all wrong with `free (p); p = NULL;`, simple, easily understood, and at most, you save 1-line with a `smartfree()` or macro. Up to you, but this somewhat is akin to micro-optimizations - time is better spent elsewhere.

Comment: @Psi Excluding pointers which go from valid to invalid dynamically as the program runs (where using NULL to represent the invalid state is good, although assigning NULL explicitly is probably better), if you're writing C and you don't know whether your pointer is still valid without checking if it's NULL, then your code is probably either wrong or badly written. It's ok in debug builds (although there I'd prefer to zap pointers with a dirtier value like 0xDEADBEEF to make use-after-free more obvious when debugging). I've written a lot of high-quality C, and this is my takeaway, YMMV.

Comment: @PaulHankin that was my question: How am I supposed to null-check my pointer if I do not reset it to NULL. Assigning NULL instead of 0 may be the better option, granted. The only issues with this macro that I can see is that it might be called upon pointers that themselves reside in dynamically allocated memory and get deallocated away in the next step (such as destroying a deep structure or a linked list). in this case, you may put in effort to set your pointers just to remove them entirely in the outer block.

Comment: I don't want errors like double-frees 'covered up' by setting pointers to null.  I want a segfault/AV at test time, not a band-aid over a bug )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard M Reese wrote a great book called - Understanding and using C pointers.
The book name is really on point. It has many scenarios for questions similar to yours.
Check pages 70-71 of that book.
It has a cool function for your question + a cool macro to easily call that function without casting the parameter we are passing.
[http://www.sauleh.ir/fc98/static_files/materials/Richard%20Reese-Understanding%20and%20Using%20C%20Pointers-O'Reilly%20Media%20(2013).pdf](http://www.sauleh.ir/fc98/static_files/materials/Richard%20Reese-Understanding%20and%20Using%20C%20Pointers-O%27Reilly%20Media%20(2013).pdf)

Comment: I don't think providing links to pirated copyright material is a good idea... This isn't PirateBay.org